# R - plot lm issues with multivariate OLS

Tags: r, least-squares, ggplot2

I am having trouble plotting multivariate `ols` regression in R using `ggplot2`. 
When I run the model without "control" variables, the regression lines are fine:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)

# model without "controls" # 
dt = mtcars %>% do(lm0 = lm(wt ~ disp + am, data = .)) %>% augment(.,lm0) 
dt$am = as.factor(dt$am)

ggplot(data = dt, aes(disp, wt) ) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data = dt, aes(disp, .fitted, group = am, colour = am)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

However, when I introduce "controls" (here for the example `hp + drat + I(drat)^2`), the lines are getting strange. I am not sure what's wrong here.

Any idea ? Any idea how to plot multivariate regressions with `ggplot` by group ?

```
dt = mtcars %>% do(lm0 = lm(wt ~ disp + am + hp + drat + I(drat)^2, data = .)) %>% augment(.,lm0) 
dt$am = as.factor(dt$am)

ggplot(data = dt, aes(disp, wt) ) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data = dt, aes(disp, .fitted, group = am, colour = am)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: What values do you suppose the software might be assigning to the other variables `am`, `hp`, and `drat` in order to make such a plot?  BTW, this does not appear to be an issue with `R`--it concerns understanding multiple regression.  Therefore, (appearances that this is just a coding issue notwithstanding), I hope people will not vote to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking whuber's suggestion into account, I did not flag the question. But maybe it is about the difference between `geom_line()` and `geom_smooth()`. In Hadley Wickham's ggplot2 book, it is briefly explained that "`geom_smooth()` fits a smoother to the data and displays the smooth and its standard error" whereas "`geom_path()` and `geom_line()` draw lines between the data points." (Wickham, 2015). So, maybe this is what you are looking for (note the `method="lm"`),

```
dt = mtcars %>% do(lm0 = lm(wt ~ disp + am + hp + drat + I(drat)^2, data = .)) %>% augment(.,lm0) 
dt$am = as.factor(dt$am)

ggplot(data = dt, aes(disp, wt) ) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(data = dt, aes(disp, .fitted, group = am, colour = am), method="lm") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

But the issue here is also what goes into `aes()` argument in the first line of the function. So, if I reproduce your second graph with `aes(disp, .fitted)` instead of `aes(disp, wt)`. It will show lines between data points as Wickham explained,

```
ggplot(data = dt, aes(disp, .fitted) ) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data = dt, aes(disp, .fitted, group = am, colour = am)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

In the end, I think this is a coding question about which arguments go into `aes()` and how variables are mapped. You map `aes(disp, wt)` but fit the line for `aes(disp, .fitted)`.

Comment: thank you for your great answer and my bet for not having read the book. But still you have to admit (if you dont have the book) that it is not straightforward in `r` to plot multivariate regression lines. For sure some packages exist (`visreg` for example) but the options are very limited. I was also surprise not to find a tutorial somewhere about how to do such basic thing. I am sure your answer will interest many even though my question missed the difference between `smooth` and `point`. Thanks again